# Is there any way to turn on/off symbolic-links (`ln -s`)?

Tags: command-line, bash, symbolic-link

There are many software which include a config file, such as nginx, supervisor.

For example, I have below config:

```
[include]
files = /mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

The real configs are located in `/mnt/etc/supervisor/avail/*.conf`
I use `ln -s /mnt/etc/supervisor/avail/a.conf /mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d/a.conf` to enable a config.

But it is annoying that I have to remove or recreate that link when turn one config off or on.

Is there any way that keep `/mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d/a.conf` exists, and change the link status? Maybe like:

```
$ cd /mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d/
$ ls -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Aug 12 09:02 a.conf -> ../avail/a.conf
$ linkoff a.conf
$ ls -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Aug 12 09:02 a.conf
$ linkon a.conf
$ ls -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Aug 12 09:02 a.conf -> ../avail/a.conf
```

This would be very convenient.

Comment: apache has these afaik. enmod, ensites do basically these things

Comment: I believe what utilities like that do, is just move or automatically create/delete the symlink, like `systemctl enable` @Anwar ?

Comment: Yes. They just create and delete symlinks

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know [you can't literally turn off a symlink, or at least not in a simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330543/how-to-turn-a-regular-file-into-a-symlink-on-linux). The symlinkness of a symlink is metadata stored in its inode, and I'm not aware of a straightforward way to write to the inode to change the file type.

Rather than deleting and recreating each time it might be easier to `mv` the symlinks to a subdirectory called `off` in the `conf.d` directory to break them so they would no longer work (because they use relative paths) and then `mv` them back into the `conf.d` directory. You could make this process easier by making functions...

#### Creating on/off bash functions

For each configuration directory you want to use these functions on, You'll need to create an `off` directory inside that directory first, for example:

```
mkdir /mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d/off
```

Next, create tiny bash functions to move the symlinks, that would work only in the directory (`conf.d` here)

Add these lines to the end of your `~/.bashrc` then type `source ~/.bashrc`

```
linkoff() { mv "$1" off ; }
linkon() { mv off/"$1" . ; }
```

Now you can type `linkoff a.conf` to `mv` `a.conf` to `off` and deactivate it, and `linkon a.conf` to turn `a.conf` back on, as long as you do this in the `conf.d` directory

If you have only one `conf.d` directory where you need to use this, you could make `linkoff a.conf` work everywhere, by making functions with full paths:

```
linkoff() { mv /mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d/"$1" /mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d/off ; }
linkon() { mv /mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d/off/"$1" /mnt/etc/supervisor/conf.d ; }
```

Comment: They'll need to create the off directory first if they want it in other places to work.

Comment: I have written that already, but I will make a line for it so it is more obvious @Anwar

Comment: `off` is a bit short for a name, but pretty optimal in this case. I would suggest creating a universal `/off` directory structure. If the symlink is located at `/path/to/symbolic/link`, move it to `/off/path/to/symbolic/link`.